# How to use "more" and "less"

Tags: phrase-usage

Drawing a contrast between Democrats and Republicans, may I say:
"Democrats think that MORE immigrants should be allowed to live and work in the USA"
and "On the contrary, Republicans think that LESS immigrants should be allowed to live and work in the USA"?
Is my use of MORE and LESS correct in these clauses?

Comment: Some pedants, myself included, would prefer **fewer** instead of **less** when modifying a countable noun: "**fewer** immigrants" (countable) but "**less** immigration" (uncountable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Democrats think that MORE immigrants should be allowed to live and work in the USA" is correct and an appropriate use of "more".

"On the contrary, Republicans think that LESS immigrants should be allowed to live and work in the USA" is not quite correct. You should use "fewer".

"Less" is used for uncountable nouns. E.g. "I have less sugar than you". "Fewer" is used for countable nouns. E.g. "I have fewer chickens than you".

"More" is used for both countable and uncountable nouns.

This rule is often ignored or unknown amongst native speakers so you will often hear "less" used for both, such as in your example sentence. It is so common that you will most likely not be corrected on it except for by someone rather pedantic.It is perhaps more common for people to incorrectly use "less" than to use "fewer". I think in the future it will stop being corrected altogether and become an acceptable usage but for now, if you want to be accurate, you should use learn to use "fewer" properly.